# return statement in the map is not working with the if else conditions. in react ant design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-redux, antd

Can someone help me to find the error in this code? The return statement in the else is working fine but the return statement in the if is not working.

But when I add a console.log in the if statement it's working. but the HTML code is not returning.

```
const renderCheckbox = ({value, record, name}) => {
    if (name == 'in_store'){
      state?.channelList?.map((element) => {
        const method = element?.fulfilment_methods?.includes('in_store');

        if(element.guid == record.channel_guid && method === true){
          return (<Checkbox key={element.guid} defaultChecked={value} onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e.target.checked, name)} />);
        }
      })

    } else {
      return <Checkbox defaultChecked={value} onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e.target.checked, name)} />;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you make sure that this code `if(element.guid == record.channel_guid && method === true)`  returns true  ?

Comment: Hi yes, thanks it's working now I missed the return at the start of the map function.

Answer (score 2):

Add `return` before `map`

```js
const renderCheckbox = ({value, record, name}) => {
    if (name == 'in_store'){
      return state?.channelList?.map((element) => {
        const method = element?.fulfilment_methods?.includes('in_store');

        if(element.guid == record.channel_guid && method === true){
          return (<Checkbox key={element.guid} defaultChecked={value} onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e.target.checked, name)} />);
        }
      })

    } 
    return <Checkbox defaultChecked={value} onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e.target.checked, name)} />;
};
```